# Why in javascript "100" < "5" returns true?

Tags: javascript, string

I had a bug in my code where I was comparing strings instead of numbers.

I was doing "100" < "5" and it was returning true.

Why does javascript think that "100" is less than "5"?

Comment: Because 1 comes before 5. It's the same reason "Aaron" comes before "Betelgeuse": lexicographical sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use `<` with strings, the [*code points*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) of the each index of the strings are compared. The code point for 1 is 49, and the code point for 5 is 53, so `'100' < '5'`, because 49 < 53.

```js
console.log(
  '1'.charCodeAt(),
  '5'.charCodeAt()
);
```

Similarly, `'A' < 'a'` because the code point for `A` (65) is smaller than the code point for `a` (97).

Comment: By "code point" you mean "ascii code" I guess?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point The ASCII range is relatively small, I'm pretty sure the logic applies to *any* Javascript string (which can have characters anywhere in the unicode range IIRC)